# About dlib::frontal_face_detector optimization

Tags: android, optimization, android-ndk, dlib

hi I'm making a app which detects face landmarks ( 68 point )

I'm in trouble optimizing system. I'm using HOG method to detect faces.

In, **detector(cv_grayscale, face_detections, -0.2);** type "dlib::frontal_face_detector& detector"

There are so many computations in there. So, android cpu cannot cover them.

So, anybody who solved this problem or relevant issues ?

```
bool DetectFacesHOG(vector<cv::Rect_<double> >& o_regions, const cv::Mat_<uchar>& intensity, dlib::frontal_face_detector& detector, std::vector<double>& o_confidences)
{

      double scaling = 1.3;
      cv::Mat_<uchar> upsampled_intensity;
      cv::resize(intensity, upsampled_intensity, cv::Size((int)(intensity.cols*scaling), (int)(intensity.rows*scaling)));

      dlib::cv_image<uchar> cv_grayscale(upsampled_intensity);
      std::vector<dlib::full_detection> face_detections;

      // millions of computation !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      detector(cv_grayscale, face_detections, -0.2);
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download latest opencv android SDK from [here.](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases)
it contains a lot of debugged samples. One of them is face detection and it detects faces with **22 frames per second** speed on my Xperia-Z5 Phone. Finally, if opencv errors cause of rotation of camera, use [this](https://github.com/dai1741/PortraitCameraSample/tree/master/PortraitCameraSample/src/jp/dai1741/android/portcamerasample) code. The code is very Clear and finds best frame resolution for your Camera View. İf you also want face recognition you can download C++ modules but  you must use **NDK(c++)**. Because Android SDK won't have face.h or other modules. You can combine detecting a face from java and recognize them from c++. Don't worry about speed opencv optimizes that. Face detecting lpcascade classificer xmls works high performance. But if you want more detect use haarcascade.